Spring Boot, React and i18next translations cause error reading 'useMemo'
I have been trying to add i18next translations to my Spring Boot and React project, but no matter what I try, as soon as I add the I18nextProvider to my App.js (or anywhere else), I get this error:
scheduler.production.min.js:13 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
at t.useMemo (react.production.min.js:26:48)
at me (I18nextProvider.js:8:17)
at gi (react-dom.production.min.js:160:137)
at Cs (react-dom.production.min.js:289:337)
at bu (react-dom.production.min.js:279:389)
at vu (react-dom.production.min.js:279:320)
at gu (react-dom.production.min.js:279:180)
at au (react-dom.production.min.js:270:88)
at ou (react-dom.production.min.js:267:429)
at E (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)

After logging this error to the browser debugger, it proceeds to correctly download my translations, but the browser ends up showing me a blank page.
I suspect that the I18nextProvider is somehow duplicated or initialised twice, since it first fails and then appears to work.
i18n initialisation code:
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import I18NextHttpBackend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n

// i18next-http-backend
// loads translations from your server
// https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
.use(I18NextHttpBackend)

// detect user language
// learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
.use(LanguageDetector)

// pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
.use(initReactI18next)

// init i18next
// for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
.init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    react: {
        useSuspense: true
    },
    initImmediate: false 
})

export default i18n;

Index.js fragment:
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PrimeReactProvider>
        <CookiesProvider>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                <Suspense fallback="...is loading">
                    <App />
                </Suspense>
            </I18nextProvider>
        </CookiesProvider>
    </PrimeReactProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

And the App:
 const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/csrf-token')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        localStorage.setItem('csrfToken', data.token);
        localStorage.setItem('csrfHeader', data.headerName);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching CSRF token:', error));
  }, []);

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<KineNavBar/>} />
        <Route path="/serviceproviders" element={<ServiceProviderSearch/>}/>
        <Route path='/serviceproviders/:id'   element={<ServiceProviderEdit/>}/>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return (<RouterProvider router={router} />);
}


It turns out i had 'npm install'ed the i18next packages to the project root directory and not the app directory. Installing the packages in the app directory fixed the problem.
